# ClipRRect Border has sharp edge instead of circular

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

```
ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                    child: ImageSlideshow(
...
```

I'm using the [ImageSlideShow](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_slideshow) package and trying to make it have circular edges, but as in this screenshot, the circular border has a sharp edge instead of getting curved evenly, why is that and how do I perfect it?

[image] [image]

Answer (score -2):

Instead of  `borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)`, you might want to go like this.

```
borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25)),
```

this should solve the problem.

Comment: This will not make a difference. The [`BorderRadius.circular`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BorderRadius/BorderRadius.circular.html) is shorthand for the `BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(..))` constructor.

Comment: Make sure to make the image fit to the size of your ```ImageSlideshow```